# Facebook c# SDK returning less results than original number

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am getting album photos and there are total of 44 photos in that album but sdk is returning me just 25 results. Is this some limitation or we have to ask for next 25? 
My code so far is:

```
dynamic photos = app.Get(AlbumList[currentAlbumSelectedIndex].Id + "/photos");

int infoCount = 0;

foreach (dynamic albumPhoto in photos.data)
{
    Classes.MyPhoto photoData = new Classes.MyPhoto();
    photoData.Id = albumPhoto.id;
    if (albumPhoto.name != null && albumPhoto.name.ToString().Length >100)
        photoData.MyPhotoName = albumPhoto.name.ToString().Substring(0, 90) + "...";
    else
        photoData.MyPhotoName = albumPhoto.name;
    byte[] imageBytes = function.GetImageFromUrl(albumPhoto.source);

    Statuslabel.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate()
    {
        if (imageBytes != null)
            photoData.MyPhotoPicture = function.GetBitmapImage(imageBytes);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        Statuslabel.Content = "Getting info of " + infoCount + " / " + photos.data.Count;
        AlbumPhotoList.Add(photoData);

        if (imageAlbumPhotos.Source == null)
        {
            imageAlbumPhotos.Source = AlbumPhotoList[0].MyPhotoPicture;
            labelAlbumPics.Content = AlbumPhotoList[0].MyPhotoName;
            AlbumPictureGetProgress.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        if (currentAlbumDisplayingPicture < AlbumList.Count - 1)
            buttonNextAlbumPic.IsEnabled = true;
    }));

    infoCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is not a problem but it is a limit that in order to keep the working efficent it returns only 25 results by default you can ask for as many results.Giving it `Offset` and `limit` Values

not the code becomes like this

```
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.limit = 50;
        parameters.offset = 0;

        dynamic friends = app.Get("me/photos",parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your example you are using the method call

```
app.Get(AlbumList[currentAlbumSelectedIndex].Id + "/photos");
```

As far as I know, you should be able to pass an `IDictionary<string, object>` as second parameter. There you define the "offset" parameter.

I read about the offset parameter in the [facebook api reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) in section Reading > Paging.

Hope this helps, Martin

Comment: this is if we use dotnet framework 4 we can omit IDictionary it makes it simplw